# [META] New user. Oy.

Tags: meta

Just how long will the site think I'm a new user?

Answer (score 6):

The [FAQ](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/faq) lists how much reputation you must have to perform certain tasks.  For instance, "New users can't create tags" will go away when you reach 250.